# Find the lim of $\frac{1}{n^2+1}+\frac{1}{n^2+2}+...+\frac{1}{(n^2+1)^2}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

Find the lim of $x_n$, if $x_n =\frac{1}{n^2+1}+\frac{1}{n^2+2}+...+\frac{1}{(n^2+1)^2}$

But it needs to be done without using integrals or logarithms. It could be easy done but the number of aditives is depending on n.
I've tried doing some structural changes in order to find some sequences $a_n$ and $b_n$ so that $a_n<x_n<b_n$ which would give us the lim of $x_n$ but I guess it's not possible hence I couldn't do that. 
The first values of $x_n$ are:

$x_1≈1.08$

$x_2≈1.73$

$x_3≈2.35$

Comment: Why $3$? Why not $2.5$ or $e$ or $\pi$ or $\infty$?

Comment: If you put $n^2+1=a$ then this is basically $H_{a^2}-H_{a}$ which acts like $\ln a$ so diverges.

Comment: I can understand not wanting to use integrals if your course didn't cover those yet. But "not using logarithms" seems like a pretty arbitrary request. Why would you want to exclude solutions that involve the logarithm function?

Comment: @Snaw: in this case, $x_n\to\infty$, which you might well be able to show without using logarithms.

Comment: @TonyK Sure we might be able to show this without using logarithms, but why would we want to? It's like saying "don't use subtraction".

Comment: Hint: It goes to infinity. Let $a_i=n^2\times 2^i$ for $i=0,1,\dots,\lfloor2\log_2 t\rfloor=:m$. Therefore we have

$$\frac{1}{n^2+1}+\frac{1}{n^2+2}+...+\frac{1}{(n^2+1)^2}\ge\sum_{j=a_0+1}^{a_1}\frac{1}j+\sum_{j=a_1+1}^{a_2}\frac{1}j+\dots+\sum_{a_{m-1}}^{a_m}\frac{1}j\ge m/2$$

Comment: @Snaw At my university we studied limits before we studied logarithms. Maybe it’s the same for OP.

Comment: Well i accept there is no reasonable cause to think that 3 is the answer btw my course covers very straightforward topics so it shouldn't be that complicated. That's the reason i made such kind of conclusion

Answer (score 2):

We have
\begin{align*}
\sum\limits_{k = 1}^{n^4  + n^2  + 1} {\frac{1}{{n^2  + k}}} & > \sum\limits_{k = 1}^{n^3 } {\frac{1}{{n^2  + k}}}  = \sum\limits_{j = 1}^n {\sum\limits_{k = (j - 1)n^2  + 1}^{jn^2 } {\frac{1}{{n^2  + k}}} } \\ & > \sum\limits_{j = 1}^n {\sum\limits_{k = (j - 1)n^2  + 1}^{jn^2 } {\frac{1}{{n^2  + jn^2 }}} }  = \sum\limits_{j = 1}^n {\frac{1}{{j + 1}}} 
\end{align*}
and the harmonic series is divergent. Thus, your sequence is divergent.